# Как реализовать выход из аккаунта?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть приложение с Firebase Auth, функция signOut лежит в MainActivity,но выход надо реализовать из MenuActivity, Intent не работает потому что вход выполнен и инициализировано значение user. Надо вызвать функцию signOut из другой активити, я не знаю как это сделать, просьба объяснить или сказать где почитать про это.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.ecohelp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;


    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";
//Инициализация всего
private EditText mEmailField;
private EditText mPasswordField;
public ProgressDialog pd;

protected FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);







    // Поля
    mEmailField = findViewById(R.id.fieldEmail);
    mPasswordField = findViewById(R.id.fieldPassword);

    // Кнопки
    findViewById(R.id.emailSignInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.emailCreateAccountButton).setOnClickListener(this);



    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

//Проверка входа
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}

private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Создание аккаунта" + email);
    if (validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pd.show();
    pd.setMessage("Регистрация");

    //Регистрация через емайл
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            pd.hide();
            Log.d(TAG, "Аккаунт успешно создан");
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user);
        } else {
            pd.hide();
            Log.w(TAG, "Ошибка создания аккаунта", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка создания аккаунта",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updateUI(null);
        }

    });
}

private void signIn(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Вход" + email);
    if (validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.show();
    pd.setMessage("Вход");

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    pd.hide();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Вход через почту успешен");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    pd.hide();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Вход не вошелся", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка входа",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }


            });
}


private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailField.setError("Пусто");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEmailField.setError(null);
    }

    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        mPasswordField.setError("Пусто");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mPasswordField.setError(null);
    }

    return !valid;
}

protected void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    updateUI(null);
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.hide();
    if (user != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.emailCreateAccountButton) {
        createAccount(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
    } else if (i == R.id.emailSignInButton) {
        signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

MenuActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;



public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.map) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (i == R.id.signOut) {
            // Как реализовать выход из аккаунта?




        }

    }
}
```

MenuActivity.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="164dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/maps"
    android:text="@string/map"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signOut"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="@string/signOut"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="422dp"
        android:layout_height="359dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/aaaaaaaaaaa" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="434dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fieldEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fieldPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailCreateAccountButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/createAccount" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailSignInButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/signIn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вы уверены что signOut() должна лежать именно в МайнАктивити? Может стоит ее перенести в Меню? Ну а если все же нет, тогда вам нужен инстанс МаинАктивити и у него дергать метод, или сделайте метод статическим и вызывайте МаинАктивити.signOut()

Comment: еще можете сделать Базовую активити от нее наследовать все другие активити и в базовой реализовать все нужные методы для общего использования с доступом протектед

Comment: Спасибо, но реализовал вот так - FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```